# Trim character from beginning and end of each array items

Tags: typescript

I would like to know how can I remove the quotations marks from the beginning and end of each item in array. The array we are receiving will look like this:

```
[ "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5", "Value6"]
```

And we will just the need that array's items to not be surrounded by quotations marks. What would be the simplest way to remove them?

Comment: What kind of data structure is that? Those are not a valid objects.

Comment: What type do you envision the items to have once the quotation marks are removed? Number? Boolean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array functions to filter and map items. Also, you can use join to join all items to one string.

```
["Value1", " Value2", null, "Value3 "].filter(item => !!item).map(item => item.trim()).join(',');

output: 'Value1,Value2,Value3'
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Updated answer.